# How is .ThenBy implemented?

Tags: c#, linq

Inspired by [this](http://www.codethinked.com/keep-your-iqueryable-in-check) I made this:

**ISortable**

```
public interface ISortable<T>
{
    IPageable<T> OrderBy<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> orderBy);
    IPageable<T> OrderByDescending<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> orderBy);
}
```

**IPageable**

```
public interface IPageable<T> : ISortable<T>, IEnumerable<T>
{
    IPageable<T> Page(int pageNumber, int pageSize);
    List<T> ToList();
    int TotalPages { get; }
    int TotalItemCount { get; }
    int PageNumber { get; }
    int? PageSize { get; }
}
```

**Pageable**

```
public class Pageable<T> : IPageable<T>
{
    private readonly IQueryable<T> _countQuery;
    private IQueryable<T> _sourceQuery;

    /// <summary>
    /// A pageable result
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceQuery">Query which holdes all relevant items.</param>
    public Pageable(IQueryable<T> sourceQuery)
    {
        _sourceQuery = sourceQuery;
        _countQuery = sourceQuery;
        PageNumber = 1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A pageable result
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceQuery">Query which holdes all relevant items.</param>
    /// <param name="countQuery">
    /// Alternative query optimized for counting.
    /// <see cref="countQuery"/> is required to give the same count as <see cref="sourceQuery"/> else paging will break. 
    /// <remarks>No checks if <see cref="sourceQuery"/> and <see cref="countQuery"/> return the same count are appiled.</remarks>
    /// </param>
    public Pageable(IQueryable<T> sourceQuery, IQueryable<T> countQuery)
        : this (sourceQuery)
    {
        _countQuery = countQuery;
    }

    #region Implementation of IEnumerable

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1"/> that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    /// <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _sourceQuery.GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.IEnumerator"/> object that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of ISortable

    public IPageable<T> OrderBy<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> orderBy)
    {
        _sourceQuery = _sourceQuery.OrderBy(orderBy);
        return this;
    }

    public IPageable<T> OrderByDescending<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> orderBy)
    {
        _sourceQuery = _sourceQuery.OrderByDescending(orderBy);
        return this;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IPageable

    public int PageNumber { get; private set; }
    public int? PageSize { get; private set; }
    public int TotalItemCount
    {
        get { return _countQuery.Count(); }
    }
    public int TotalPages
    {
        get { return (int) (Math.Ceiling((double) TotalItemCount/PageSize ?? 1)); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Chop a query result into pages.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pageNumber">Page number to fetch. Starting from 1.</param>
    /// <param name="pageSize">Items per page.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IPageable<T> Page(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        PageNumber = pageNumber;
        PageSize = pageSize;

        _sourceQuery = _sourceQuery
            .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize);

        return this;
    }

    public List<T> ToList()
    {
        return _sourceQuery.ToList();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The above works. Great success! :)

However I've run into a problem implementing the method `.ThenBy()`. The problem is that `.ThenBy()` should only be accessible when `.OrderBy()` has been called.

I noticed that [IQueryable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264.aspx) returns an IOrderedQueryable and that's where the access to `.ThenBy()` comes from. But in order to make my current solution work I'd need to make a IOrderedPageable and a new OrderedPagable to go with it. The OrderedPagable would be an almost exact copy of Pageable which is really really bad design.

I highly doubt that's how it's done in LINQ. So my question is, how did they do it? I'm very curious :)

One thing I did notice is that pretty much all the LINQ methods are extension methods, is that part of the "trick" :)?

Comment: Make `IOrderedPageable` extend from `IPageable`? The extension methods are indeed part of the trick in that there is not much to the implementation of an `OrderedEnumerable` - all it needs is to implement `IEnumerable` in a way that sorts the elements before yielding them. The extension methods in `Enumerable` provide implementations of the LINQ methods for any `IEnumerable`. The problem you have is that your current design is much "heavier" and non-lazy - you can't add sorting **after** a page has been selected.

Comment: Personally I'd scrap the LINQ-like design completely since it's very confusing. LINQ enumerables are all stateless, while your `OrderBy` and other methods clearly modify the state of a single object.

Comment: How are "LINQ enumerables" stateless?  For example, `Distinct` maintains state: a set of elements already yielded so as not to yield them again.

Comment: @MichaelPetito Stateless is not the right word I guess. I meant that every LINQ method returns a new enumerable whose state is completely independent of any state the previous enumerable in the chain maintains. I.e. if you do `var list2 = list.OrderBy(...)` then enumerating over `list` will still yield the items in the original order.

Comment: When you think about Linq, the call `items.OrderBy(x => x.Age).ThenBy(x => x.Name)` will do something completely different than `items.OrderBy(x => x.Age).OrderBy(x => x.Name)`. Have you thought about how that's possible? `ThenBy` in Linq needs more info than what is inside an `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: Anyway, back from the derail: Because of how LINQ chaining works, **and** because of how LINQ is implemented (using extension methods), successive calls of `OrderBy()` have the somewhat behaviour of the collection being sorted with the last sort expression having the highest priority. The reason behind this is that the chain of enumerables causes the collection to be sorted repeatedly, using the first provided sort expression first, the second one after, etc. The point of `IOrderedEnumerable` and its `ThenBy()` to give you an enumerable that will apply the sorts in the "correct" order.

Comment: Now, in your case, you clearly don't need to ape this design if you don't need the extension-based design or chaining behaviour for `ISortable`. Just base your design around `ISortable` implementations that keep a mutable list of sort expressions that are applied in the correct order before you need to evaluate the query. I'll try and make an outline in an answer.

Comment: How does LINQ do it? In LINQ, `IOrderedQueryable` extends `IQueryable` adding the `.ThenBy()` methods (and possibly others). `Queryable` is a static class implementing the `I(Ordered)Queryable` methods as extension methods. `.ThenBy()` is only added to `IOrderedQueryable` (by way of its parameter `this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source`), meaning you'll not be allowed to call it on an `IQueryable` - although the concrete object you're calling it on may very well implement `IOrderedQueryable` too, you're limited to the methods on the interface returned from the previous call in the chain.

Comment: Now, ignoring how LINQ does it, the real "trick" in terms of the fluent API is simply that a single class may implement multiple interfaces, letting the returned interface from one call determine what methods can be called next. You don't need extension methods for that.

Comment: @JimmiTh Could you elaborate on this in an answer, perhaps give a code example?

Comment: @JimmiTh For enumerables, it's probably done with [`IOrderedEnumerable.CreateOrderedEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548559.aspx) that any ordered enumerable must implement to allow creating "derived" orderings.

Comment: Personally, my recommendation would be to lose the fluent API approach here since it's essentially based on not really knowing how LINQ is internally structured, and creating a simpler API surface altogether.

Comment: @millimoose - yeah, I'm ignoring the implementation details, since they're *very* far from what Snæbjørn is doing - only focusing on how the fluent API works, since that's what seems to be asked: how to make sure ".ThenBy() should only be accessible when .OrderBy() has been called."

Comment: @JimmiTh Yeah, and my solution would be just having a single method, that acts "intuitively" (successive calls mean a smaller priority given to the sort key), and another method to reset the ordering, since you're not constrained by LINQ's design of chained lazily evaluated sequences.

Comment: @Snæbjørn - I would prefer not to elaborate in an answer, since I very much agree with millimoose that this is not the best way to do it in your case. The above was added as a comment, because that's what it is - not a solution. :-)

Comment: @JimmiTh fair enough :)

Comment: Won't directly answer your question, but it might be worthwhile reading Jon Skeet's 'Reimplementing LINQ to Objects' series - see http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like your class `OrderedPageable` could be a subclass of `Pageable` and additionally implement the `IOrderedPageable` interface.

The inheritance approach would seem to make sense, since anything that handles `Pageable` should likely be able to handle `OrderedPageable` in the same way.

---

By slightly changing your interfaces and using an interface inheritance approach similar to the above, you can achieve the functionality you're looking for with immutable queryable classes and extension methods.

In my opinion, the usage is clearer and more consistent with LINQ.

Examples:

```
query.AsPageable(100).Page(1);
query.AsPageable(100).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ThenBy(x => x.Age).Page(1).ToList();
```

I haven't tested this but the concept should work.  Note that:

- the total item count is computed from the original query (not any of the sorted queries)
- the total item count is lazy and only computed once
- depending on your query provider, you may have to expose a `SourceQuery` property of `IPageableQuery` for use within `PageableExtensions`, as your query provider may not successfully translate queries against this new `PageableQuery` type.

Interfaces:

```
public interface IPageableQuery<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
    int TotalPages { get; }
    int TotalItemCount { get; }

    int PageSize { get; }
}

public interface IOrderedPageableQuery<T> : IPageableQuery<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
}
```

Implementations:

```
public class PageableQuery<T> : IPageableQuery<T>
{
    readonly IQueryable<T> _sourceQuery;
    readonly Lazy<int> _totalItemCount; 

    public int TotalPages { get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)TotalItemCount / PageSize); } }
    public int TotalItemCount { get { return _totalItemCount.Value; } }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }

    public PageableQuery(IQueryable<T> sourceQuery, int pageSize)
    {
        _sourceQuery = sourceQuery;
        _totalItemCount = new Lazy<int>(() => _sourceQuery.Count());

        PageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return _sourceQuery.GetEnumerator();}
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

    public Expression Expression { get { return _sourceQuery.Expression; } }
    public Type ElementType { get { return _sourceQuery.ElementType; } }
    public IQueryProvider Provider { get { return _sourceQuery.Provider; } }
}

public class OrderedPageableQuery<T> : IOrderedPageableQuery<T>
{
    readonly IPageableQuery<T> _sourcePageableQuery;
    readonly IOrderedQueryable<T> _sourceQuery;

    public int TotalPages { get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)TotalItemCount / PageSize); } }
    public int TotalItemCount { get { return _sourcePageableQuery.TotalItemCount; } }
    public int PageSize { get { return _sourcePageableQuery.PageSize; } }

    public OrderedPageableQuery(IPageableQuery<T> sourcePageableQuery, IOrderedQueryable<T> newSourceQuery)
    {
        _sourcePageableQuery = sourcePageableQuery;
        _sourceQuery = newSourceQuery;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return _sourceQuery.GetEnumerator();}
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

    public Expression Expression { get { return _sourceQuery.Expression; } }
    public Type ElementType { get { return _sourceQuery.ElementType; } }
    public IQueryProvider Provider { get { return _sourceQuery.Provider; } }
}
```

Extension Methods:

```
public static class PageableExtension
{
    public static IPageableQuery<T> AsPageable<T>(this IQueryable<T> sourceQuery, int pageSize)
    {
        return new PageableQuery<T>(sourceQuery, pageSize);
    }

    public static IOrderedPageableQuery<T> OrderBy<T, U>(this IPageableQuery<T> sourcePageableQuery, Expression<Func<T, U>> orderBy)
    {
        return new OrderedPageableQuery<T>(sourcePageableQuery, Queryable.OrderBy(sourcePageableQuery, orderBy));
    }

    public static IOrderedPageableQuery<T> OrderByDescending<T, U>(this IPageableQuery<T> sourcePageableQuery, Expression<Func<T, U>> orderBy)
    {
        return new OrderedPageableQuery<T>(sourcePageableQuery, Queryable.OrderByDescending(sourcePageableQuery, orderBy));
    }

    public static IOrderedPageableQuery<T> ThenBy<T, U>(this IOrderedPageableQuery<T> sourcePageableQuery, Expression<Func<T, U>> orderBy)
    {
        return new OrderedPageableQuery<T>(sourcePageableQuery, Queryable.ThenBy(sourcePageableQuery, orderBy));
    }

    public static IOrderedPageableQuery<T> ThenByDescending<T, U>(this IOrderedPageableQuery<T> sourcePageableQuery, Expression<Func<T, U>> orderBy)
    {
        return new OrderedPageableQuery<T>(sourcePageableQuery, Queryable.ThenByDescending(sourcePageableQuery, orderBy));
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> Page<T>(this IPageableQuery<T> sourceQuery, int pageNumber)
    {
        return sourceQuery.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * sourceQuery.PageSize)
                          .Take(sourceQuery.PageSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try that approach. But I found out I had to override a lot of methods in `OrderedPageable`. `.OrderBy` `.OrderByDecending` `.Page` would have to be overridden to return IOrderedPageable and use a new _sourceQuery which was of type IOrderedQueryable, and as I kept reading through the code I came up with all kinds of scenarios where the class state would not be as expected. So I scrapped it as not the way to go :/

Comment: I absolutely agree with "usage is clearer and more consistent with LINQ". This looks very promising, gonna play around with it for a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

My suggested design for this would be making it explicit that your methods are in fact mutating the source object and deliberately not mirroring LINQ method names to avoid confusion. I omitted the `IPageable` interface and a bunch of other stuff for clarity, since the code is already a bit lengthy:

```
public interface ISortable<T>
{
    Pageable<T> ResetOrder();
    Pageable<T> AddOrder(Expression<Func<T, object>> orderBy);
    Pageable<T> AddOrderDescending(Expression<Func<T, object>> orderBy);
}

public class Pageable<T> : ISortable<T>, IEnumerable<T> {
    class SortKey {
        public Expression<Func<T, object>> Expression { get; set; }
        public bool Descending { get; set; }
    }

    List<SortKey> _sortKeys = new List<SortKey>();

    System.Linq.IQueryable<T> _sourceQuery;

    int _pageNumber;
    int _pageSize;

    public Pageable<T> SetPage(int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
        _pageNumber = pageNumber;
        _pageSize = pageSize;
        return this;
    }

    public Pageable<T> ResetOrder()
    {
        _sortKeys.Clear();
        return this;
    }

    public Pageable<T> AddOrder(Expression<Func<T, object>> orderBy)
    {
        _sortKeys.Add(new SortKey {
            Expression = orderBy, 
            Descending = false
        });
        return this;
    }

    public Pageable<T> AddOrderDescending(Expression<Func<T, object>> orderBy)
    {
        _sortKeys.Add(new SortKey {
            Expression = orderBy, 
            Descending = true
        });
        return this;
    }

    IEnumerable<T> SortAndPage()
    {
        if (_sortKeys.Count == 0) 
        {
            return Page(_sourceQuery);
        }

        var firstKey = _sortKeys[0];
        var orderedQuery = firstKey.Descending 
            ? _sourceQuery.OrderByDescending(firstKey.Expression) 
            : _sourceQuery.OrderBy(firstKey.Expression);

        foreach (var key in _sortKeys.Skip(1)) 
        {
            orderedQuery = key.Descending ? orderedQuery.ThenByDescending(key.Expression) : orderedQuery.ThenBy(key.Expression);
        }
        return Page(orderedQuery);
    }

    IEnumerable<T> Page(IQueryable<T> query) 
    {
        return query.Skip((_pageNumber - 1) * _pageSize)
                    .Take (_pageSize);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return SortAndPage().GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Note that the source query remains the same so you could change the parameters before enumerating the elements. This would also let you implement chaining behaviour if you wanted by returning a new `Pageable` based on the current one instead of `this` in the methods that do that, but it would make the code even clunkier since you'd have create a copy constructor and add code to create those derived objects.

Also I believe the annoying redundant code in `SortAndPage()` could be refactored (or at least golfed down) using some FP approaches but it's probably more straightforward to read the way it is.